# need help on changing control template based on invoking assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a style in it's control template i have two borders. Part_Border and Part_Border1, Part_Border is default. And this style is located in a assembly called "Themes.dll".

I have two products Product-A and Product-B. When Product-B calls the Themes.dll then we have to use "Part_Border1" where as if Product-A calls Themes.dll then Part_Border(which is default) should apply.

How can we do this in WPF? please share your ideas.

Comment: Why you want to create Themes.dll ? .. you can use separately means        Create style Part_Border inside Product-A and Part_Border1 inside Product-B

Comment: We have many products and all these products should have consistent look and feel for that reason we are keeping all our resources in a single dll and asking other product developers to use. we cannot create separate resources for each product.